# Проблемы с Flex-direction

Tags: css, css3

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.nav li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20px"Montserrat";
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  margin: 5px;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background: #ff4848;
  color: #fff;
}
.content {
  width: 65%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column {
  background: #ff8e8e;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<! Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Live or Life</li>
      <li>Live or Life</li>
      <li>Live or Life</li>
      <li>Live or Life</li>
      <li>Live or Life</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="column cl-a">
        <h2> quamquam iis laboris cohaerescant cupidatat efflorescere</h2>
        <p>Dolore mandaremus te quid nulla qui incididunt nisi ingeniis est summis tempor nam comprehenderit ita officia te legam et excepteur summis nostrud ea deserunt nulla sunt do duis iis pariatur in lorem ingeniis ad ad elit culpa ex appellat. Lorem
          eiusmod iis magna quae, labore possumus sempiternum iis ut quis labore ab iudicem ubi eram pariatur o aliqua minim de qui iis labore aliquip, eu proident ut officia in et multos proident reprehenderit, et amet arbitrantur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column cl-b">
        <h2> admodum voluptatibus vidisse imitarentur id praesentibus</h2>
        <p>Nescius summis sunt arbitror magna. Tamen excepteur ubi varias malis, aute concursionibus quibusdam minim litteris, enim incurreret philosophari, quid admodum ab exercitation, si quorum appellat ab ad quae velit e senserit nam ita elit cupidatat
          appellat, quem laborum in malis eram. Eram excepteur efflorescere, si minim ingeniis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column cl-c">
        <h2> dolor litteris iudicem tractavissent distinguantur quo</h2>
        <p>Cernantur comprehenderit si incididunt quo consequat quid enim tempor minim an multos aliquip et ipsum nulla, singulis aliqua quae tempor esse. Te esse excepteur, enim ab laboris se ea cillum qui legam id cupidatat duis dolore ea irure. Ita vidisse
          illustriora aut ita fore cupidatat quibusdam iis ita eu nulla probant, ut multos a illum. Si eram sempiternum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Почему `flex-direction` у класса `content` не работает? В классе `nav` все хорошо. Когда убрал свойство `flex-wrap: wrap` у класса `content`, все `flex-direction: row\column` применяются. В классе `nav`, не убирая `flex-wrap: wrap`, `flex-direction: row\column;` работает.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Текстовые тэги в html по умолчанию будут занимать всю ширину своего контейнера. В вашем случае тэги параграфов растягивают дивы с классом column и поэтому каждая из колонок занимает всю ширину. Что бы исправить это вы можете присвоить фиксированную ширину к классу column как например width: 200px и это позволит уместить все три ваших дива внутри одной строки внутри дива content как минимум на десктопных устройствах. Хорошей практикой может быть задание фиксированной ширины контейнера и колонок и регулирование их с помощью меди запросов.

[Ссылка на простое решение на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9L2fndt/)

```
.column {
  background: #ff8e8e;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

А так же если вы хотите писать более валидный код, то если посмотреть на документацию на [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp) для свойствa flex-direction то мы увидим что для его использования необходимо прописать свойства display и flex-direction, а так же перфиксы с ними. В вашем коду у класса content прописан display и отсутствует webkit-display и присутствует.

Если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, пометьте его как верный.

Comment: нет не правильно я уже решил надо было оказывается добавить к дочерним элементам свойство flex: 1; и  все